# Probability of winning a draw in volleyball

Tags: probability

In volleyball game the result is $24:24$ The teams continue to play until the absolute difference between the scores is $2$. What is the probability of winning the game for each team? Intuitively it is $50\%$ for both teams but how to prove it mathematically? In case the teams will alternately get points the game will be infinitely long. Could you please provide a hint how to deal with this kind of problems?

Comment: You may want to assume each team is equally likely to score on each point and that points are independent (the pre-1999 rules only allowed the serving team to score, making this assumption false)

Comment: If both teams have probability of e.g. $0.9$ to score by serving then the team that is on serve has a probability $>0.9^2=0.81$ to win (if they score by serving then are allowed to serve again).

Comment: I wold say the serving team has an advantage, although I'd be hard pressed to calculate how much. The server gets to decide how powerfully he'll serve, to which player (a substitute, one who's missed 2-3 in a row, etc.), from what position behind the service line, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Probability of team A getting 25th point=Probability of team B getting 25th point=1/2.
 Let the score be 25:24.

Now if team A gets point, it will win but if team B scores, game will continue.
 Probability of A getting a 27th point=1/2.

Now, Probability of a team winning the game = Probability of team A winning the game = Probability of team B winning the game = $1/2*1/2=1/4$

Cross checking:
$P(A)+P(B)+P(draw)=1/4+1/4+1/2=1$
And it goes on.
So $P(A)=P(B)=1/4+1/8+1/16+1/32$ . . . $=1/2$

Comment: I don't agree that the P(team A scores first) = P(team B scores first), as one team has the serve and, I think, therefore has an advantage.....

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the first team wins their serve with probability $p_1$ and the second team wins their serve with probability $p_2$. The state diagram will look like this:

[image]

From the state $0_1$ (even score, first team to serve) we go to the state $+1$ with probability $p_1$, from there we can go to the state $0_2$ (even score, second team to serve) with probability $1 - p_1$, and so on. Instead of taking an infinite sum over all possible paths, we can write a system of equations for the probabilities of the first team winning the set starting from a given state:
$$P_{0_1} = p_1 P_{+1} + (1 - p_1) P_{-1}, \\
P_{+1} = p_1 + (1 - p_1) P_{0_2}, \\
P_{0_2} = (1 - p_2) P_{+1} + p_2 P_{-1}, \\
P_{-1} = (1 - p_2) P_{0_1}.$$
Solving this system, we obtain
$$P_{0_1} = \frac {p_1^2} {p_1 (1 - p_2) (p_1 + p_2) + p_2^2}.$$
If $p_1 > 1/\sqrt 2$, the first team wins with a probability higher than $1/2$, regardless of how well the second team serves. If $p_1$ is smaller, the first team is more likely to win if
$$ p_2 < \frac {p_1} 2 \left( \sqrt \frac {5 - p_1} {1 - p_1} - 1 \right).$$
In volleyball, typically the serving team has a disadvantage. For $p_1 \approx .4$, the teams are equally likely to win if $p_2 \approx .35$.

If $p_2 = p_1$, we have
$$P_{0_1} = \frac 1 {3 - 2 p_1}.$$
If both teams are equally hopeless on their serve, winning with the same very small probability, the second team wins the set with a probability close to $2/3$.

Comment: The serving team has a disadvantage?! Why do you say that? I would say the exact opposite.

Comment: The receiving team is more likely to win the point; see [here](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/serving-is-a-disadvantage-in-some-olympic-sports).

Comment: OK, one "study" about it, but I don't see that as definitive. Here's what I keep coming back to.....In order to win a set, a team must score more points than its opponent. If Team A wins the game before 24:24 (or 14:14 in the decisive set), that means that Team A won more points *while it was serving* than it lost while serving. If the score reaches a tie-break situation, then the team that wins the set/match will be the one who *serves* the last point.

I still contend that the serving team has the advantage.

Comment: By "the serving team has a disadvantage" I mean that it's more realistic to take $p_1 < 1/2, \,p_2 < 1/2$.

Comment: Again, taking a step back from the actual math, the only way for a team to win is if it wins a string of points *on its serve* either in the middle of the set or the last two points of the set, in case it's gone to a 24:24 tie..... you can *only* win the set if you win your serves. Ergo, it's not a disadvantage to be the serving team.

Comment: Consider the case $p_1 = p_2$. We start watching the set in the state $0_1$. After the first point, we transition into one of the two exactly symmetric situations. But if $p_1 < 1/2$, it's more likely that we transition into the situation which is less favorable to the first team (since $P_{+1} > 1/2$).

Comment: I disagree with "exactly symmetric situations"...If you have 2 sprinters lined up for a 100m dash, they are both in "exactly symmetric situations." But, when you add the element of one team serves / the other receives, the situations are no longer symmetric. And, again, the only way to win a set is by winning at least two points on serve. Your calculations with p(1), p(2), etc. are based on the situations being the same, which they are not.

Comment: I'm saying that the states $+1$ and $-1$ are symmetric if $p_1 = p_2$.

Comment: That goes without saying, but since there is no reason to believe that p1 = p2, I'm not sure how that's relevant.